# What do scriptures say about vairagya at early ages?

Tags: scripture, grihastha, non-attachment, age

Most of the people think that vairagya is not good during early ages (say 10 - 30). I am asking this question for people who are practicing Grihastha (householder) ashram.

What do scriptures tell about this? Is it okay for a person to attain vairagya at early age?

Comment: Vairagya is a state of mind. A person can attain vairagya at any age.